# Typescript - check type in runtime and warn about errors

Tags: angular, typescript

**INTRODUCTION**

I'm using Angular 6.

Angular uses typescript, so you can type your function's arguments:

```
public fun1(aaa: number) {
  console.log(aaa);
}
```

If I'll try to call `fun1` with parameter of other type - I'll get an error:

```
public fun2() {
  this.fun1([1, 2, 3]); // TS2345: Argument of type 'number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'
}
```

**THE PROBLEM**

Type checking works well if I can control the arguments in my files.

But maybe `fun1` is called with some parameters which I get from backend.

Typescript doesn't workin in runtime, so it won't show any errors, the code of `fun1` would just run with `[1, 2, 3]`.

-- edited --

Backend response is not the only source of problem. Sometimes a library can change type of your data and you might not know about it. An example would be using Reactive Forms with a control which should be a number - it's converted to string when you edit the number.

**QUESTION**

Is there some common way to handle type checking in runtime?

I thought about something like:

```
public fun1(aaa: number) {
  if (typeof aaa !== 'number') {
    console.warn('wrong type');
  } else {
    console.log(aaa);
  }
}
```

, but WebStorm then tells me `typeof check is always false: 'aaa' always has type 'number'`.

Also putting something like this at the top of every function seems like adding a lot of unnecessary code.

Does someone have a good solution for this?

Comment: i think you are passing array of number instead of number.

Comment: The `HttpClient` in Angular allows you to hint the shape of the API response you're expecting. If you really wanted you could also validate it at that boundary, so you don't spread runtime type checking throughout the whole app.

Comment: @jack ofc I'm passing array of numbers, the problem is - if I do it in typescript files it will give me errors, but if I will get it from some other source (like backend response) then I won't get any errors.

Answer (score 5):

TypeScript - by design - does not provide runtime type information (see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals, Non-goals, point 5).

If you feed TypeScript with some external data (maybe passed in data-attributes in HTML or fetched from REST API), TypeScript cannot know about its type. But there are some solutions. We'll have a look at two of them.

One approach you can take is to circumvent type system with `as` operator. This is not a type safe approach (you introduce a hole in a type system) but it's (at least partially) in line with TypeScript goals (see a link above).

Let's pretend that `fetchApiSync` function call returns just a simple javascript object `{name: "John", age: 42}` and we have a function:

```
function introduceMe(person: Person) {
    return `My name is ${person.name} and I'm ${person.age} years old.`
}
```

along with an interface

```
interface Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}
```

Now let's do the following:

`const person: Person = fetchPersonFromApi(1);`.

Clearly, we would like `fetchPersonFromApi` to return a value that matches `Person` interface so that we can do:

`const introduction = introduceMe(person);`

To achieve it, we can do something like this:

```
function fetchPersonFromApi(id: number): Person {
   // it's synchronous and without error handling just for brevity
   const response: Person = fetchApiSync(`/persons/${id}`) as Person

   return response;
}
```

It type checks as we did an explicit cast of whatever we get from an API to a Person when we used `as Person`. It's "necessary" because `fetchApiSync` has no way to know about the types of the values that it gets from an external API. Of course, we run into problems when instead of a value of type Person we get a value of some other type but there is nothing that we can do about it... or can we?

Another variant of this option is to use `any` (or `unknown` from TS 3) types. These two allow you to skip the type checks - value of type `any` can be assigned to "any" type, including `Person`. But errors can be hard to trace as you have an unchecked value inside your type system. Use it wisely!

Second approach that you can take is to use `io-ts` library (https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts). It allows you to specify `runtime types` and perform type checks on runtime (hence, it introduces an overhead of validating if a value matches a type). Moreover, you need to specify those types in slightly different manner (see documentation) so that they can exist on runtime. Good thing to note is that io-ts allows you to derive your pure-TypeScript type from io-ts type definitions. Using io-ts allows you to stay more type safe and protect your codebase from nasty casting or using `any` type (or `unknown` type from TypeScript 3). It does so at some cost - a part of which is non-negligible complexity.

Comment: 2nd approach looks promising and I'll take a look on that, thanks. I'm already using 1st one, but it's not enough, because backend response is not the only thing which could pass unwanted types (other example would be Reactive Forms, I edited my question to add this example).